# Pandas CSV Table to html Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have this csv that i read with pandas and i want to show it in the html as table. How can i do that? i tried to parse dataset as dataset and do loops in the html like for i in dataset print i . but it doesnt work. Any tips?

This is the flask py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from pylab import rcParams
import numpy as np
# import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
# from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
@app.route('/preprocessing')
def about_page():
    return render_template('preprocessing.html', data=dataset)


dataset = pd.read_csv('Data_Covid_Bandung.csv',index_col=[0],parse_dates = [0])
```

and this is the table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For whatever dataframe, you can convert it to a number of output formats:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,2,3], y=[2,3,4]))
df.to_html()
```

resulting string:

```
'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>x</th>\n      <th>y</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>1</td>\n      <td>2</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>1</th>\n      <td>2</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <th>2</th>\n      <td>3</td>\n      <td>4</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

Comment: but how can i use that to html? when i put it to my html file it print literal <table .... not making a table